# Strange behavior when functions created in pthread_create accept pointer-to-int

Tags: c, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *runner(void * p)
{
    int *line = p;
    printf("line: %d\n", *line);
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t tid[2];                                                                                                       
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        pthread_create(&tid[i], 0, runner, &i);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)                                                                                                       
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

For the above code I expect the output to be

```
line 0
line 1
```

But the output is actually

```
line 1
line 2
```

So what is wrong with this code? How did `i` get incremented? Do I have to pass `struct`s to the runner function?

Comment: Could just as easily be 2 2, 2 1, 0 2, etc. Read up on race conditons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guarantee that `printf("line: %d\n", *line);` line will finish before `pthread_create` returns, which means you have a race on `i`.
(The main thread tries to increment it and the new threads try to read it
via their argument pointer).

You can solve the problem by passing pointers to different objects (one per thread, optimally cache-aligned, but that hardly matters here):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *runner(void * p)
{
    int *line = p;
    printf("line: %d\n", *line);
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t tid[2];
    int ints[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        ints[i]=i;
        if(pthread_create(&tid[i], 0, runner, &ints[i])) return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

or by passing the `i` by value (by casting it to `void*`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void *runner(void * p)
{
    printf("line: %d\n", (int)(intptr_t)p);
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t tid[2];
    int ints[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if(pthread_create(&tid[i], 0, runner, (void*)(intptr_t)i)) return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    return 0;
}
```