# variable in thread callstack changing unexpectedly c

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

Using c11 threads, I'm trying to ensure that `foo` is thread safe. While `foo` isn't reentrant, I'm trying to mitigate this with mutexes.

I don't understand why the value of `thrdn` is changing in the critical loop. My understanding was that each threaded call to `foo` would have its own version of `thrdn`, but it seems that it is being modified by other threads at run-time.

I've tried moving the `mtx_lock` above `thrdn`'s declaration and changing `thrdn` to be of type `atomic_int *` however these both result in the same behaviour.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <threads.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define THREAD_MAX 5

thrd_t threads[THREAD_MAX];
mtx_t mtx;

void foo(void * data)
{
        int* thrdn = (int *)data;

        mtx_lock(&mtx);
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                printf("thread %d, number %d\n", *thrdn, i);
        }
        mtx_unlock(&mtx);
}

int main()
{
        mtx_init(&mtx, mtx_plain | mtx_recursive);
        for(int i = 0; i < THREAD_MAX; ++i){
                thrd_create(&threads[i], foo, &i);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < THREAD_MAX; ++i){
                thrd_join(threads[i], NULL);
        }
        mtx_destroy(&mtx);
}
```

Comment: `&i` is the address of a single `i` variable, which has a rather limited lifetime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange behavior when functions created in pthread\_create accept pointer-to-int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60828040/strange-behavior-when-functions-created-in-pthread-create-accept-pointer-to-int)

Comment: Strange that pretty much the same scenario is asked about twice in a few hours... wonder if the two of you are in the same class or something? Though that one uses pthreads, not C11 threads so maybe not...

Comment: Each execution of `foo()` *does* have its own `thrdn`, and they all point to the *same* local variable `i` of the main thread's execution of `main()`. At least until that variable's lifetime ends.

Comment: I think you might have a point @Groo, I'd thought that it would be safe to use &i within the loop, but if it ends before the threads complete that could be the issue.

Comment: The lifetime issue is indeed important, @Mokou, but it's not the headliner here.  Even if you lifted the declaration of `i` out of the loop to resolve the lifetime issue, you would still have data races related to it.

Comment: NOTE: The value of `thrdn` doesn't change. It's the value of `*thrdn` that is changing. If that is not obvious to you, then IMO you should spend more time learning the basics of the language before you dive into learning about multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been noted in the comments, the issue was the reference to the local variable `i`. Tracking thread ids separately as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60828218/11058021) answer solved the issue.